# How can I iterate through elements with a delay using Bluebird Promises?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

My code so far is:

```
  Promise.map startEndTimes, (startEndTime) ->
    Promise.delay 10000
    .then ->
      oandaClient.getCandlesAsync "#{dbInstrument.base}_#{dbInstrument.quote}", startEndTime.startTime, startEndTime.endTime, 'S5'
  .then (candles) ->
    console.log candles
```

This is not really working. I have `startEndTimes` as an array. I want to, for each of them, get data from Oanda, then process that data. I don't want to kick off all the calls at once, but rather have them sequential. Is this possible? If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run the promises in sequence, you can use `Promise.reduce()` for that:

```
Promise.reduce startEndTimes, (total, startEndTime) ->
    oandaClient getCandlesAsync( 
        "#{dbInstrument.base}_#{dbInstrument.quote}" 
        startEndTime.startTime
        startEndTime.endTime
        'S5'
    ).then (candles) ->
        console.log candles
        total.concat candles    
, []
.then (allCandles) ->
    # use allCandles
```

If you want to precede each call with a delay as you are running them in sequence, you can do that too:

```
Promise.reduce startEndTimes, (total, startEndTime) ->
    Promise.delay 10000
    .then () -> 
        oandaClient getCandlesAsync( 
            "#{dbInstrument.base}_#{dbInstrument.quote}" 
            startEndTime.startTime
            startEndTime.endTime
            'S5'
        )
    .then (candles) ->
        console.log candles
        total.concat candles    
, []
.then (allCandles) ->
    # use allCandles
```

Answer (score 2):

Your delays are running all in parallel, as `Promise.map` calls the callback on all elements immediately and then waits for all promises.

You seem to be looking for the [`concurrency` option](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#option-concurrency) of the `map` function, which lets you limit the number of promises that are pending at the same time. Passing `1` will make it process your array sequentially:

```
Promise.map startEndTimes, (startEndTime) ->
  oandaClient.getCandlesAsync "#{dbInstrument.base}_#{dbInstrument.quote}", startEndTime.startTime, startEndTime.endTime, 'S5'
, concurrency: 1
.then (candles) ->
  console.log candles
```

Comment: Bluebird's got a feature for everything, doesn't it? +1

Comment: For many things, yes :-) I've seen things that are not as easily managed, but they're very rare.